# Select specific lines with awk but not range

Tags: awk

I would like to select lines from file. I'm interested in three specific lines.

Input:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
```

Output:

```
line2
line3
line7
```

There is no specific pattern of selecting lines.
I'm familiar with sed solution:

```
sed -n '2p; 3p; 7p' file
```

However I'm using awk to select specific fields of those lines afterwards. Therefore I would prefer to use awk alone instead of piping sed and awk. Still I cannot find simple solution with awk.

Comment: `awk 'FNR==2 || FNR==3 || FNR==7' Input_file` is this what you are looking for? This will print 2nd, 3rd, 7th lines from file.

Comment: Or if you are wearing your fancy pants: `awk -v p=2,3,7 'BEGIN{split(p,a,/,/);for(i in a)b[a[i]]}(FNR in b)' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
awk 'FNR ~ /^(2|3|7)$/{print}'
```

Should do the trick quite neatly

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{a[2]=a[3]=a[7]=1}(NR in a){print}' file.txt
```

output

```
line2
line3
line7
```

Explanation: I use array `a` where I set value for keys `2` and `3` and `7`. If current number row (`NR`) is one of keys set I `print` said line.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{split("2 3 7",tmp); for (i in tmp) nrs[tmp[i]]} NR in nrs' file
line2
line3
line7
```

Comment: This makes the notation for longer numbers easier ++

Comment: @Thefourthbird It'd also be faster than a regexp comparison as in the currently accepted answer since it's just doing a hash lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Using a character class to match `2` `3` or `7` and `FNR` to match the record number of the current file:

```
awk 'FNR ~ /^[237]$/' file
```

Output

```
line2
line3
line7
```

If you have a large file and yo u know the maximum line you can also stop processing when you reach it:

```
awk 'FNR ~ /^[237]$/{
  print
  if (FNR == 7) exit
}' file
```